# pact-jvm-provider-spring-mvc json4s exception

Tags: spring, pact

Just trying to understand pact. We are using spring boot, so naturally I went to trying simple setup using pact-jvm-provider-spring-mvc.
My pact file is a simple 

`{
  "consumer": {
    "name": "MyConsumer"
  },
  "provider": {
    "name": "MyProvider"
  },
  "interactions": [
    {
      "description": "a request for projects",
      "providerState": "i have a list of projects",
      "request": {
        "method": "GET",
        "path": "/dogs",
        "headers": {
          "Accept": "application/json"
        }
      },
      "response": {
        "status": 200,
        "headers": {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "body": [
          {
            "dog": "1"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "metadata": {
    "pactSpecification": {
      "version": "2.0.0"
    }
  }
}`

I added these dependencies to my gradle build:

```

testCompile group: 'com.reagroup', name: 'pact-jvm-provider-spring-mvc_2.10', version: '0.4.0'
    testCompile group: 'au.com.dius', name: 'pact-jvm-provider_2.10', version: '2.4.18'
    testCompile group: 'au.com.dius', name: 'pact-jvm-provider-junit_2.11', version: '3.4.1'
```

The test class doesn't do much, just creates a controller in spring fashion.

But what I get from running it is

```

org.json4s.package$MappingException: Case classes defined in function bodies are not supported.

```
at org.json4s.reflect.package$.fail(package.scala:96)
at org.json4s.reflect.Reflector$ClassDescriptorBuilder$$anonfun$9.apply(Reflector.scala:115)
at org.json4s.reflect.Reflector$ClassDescriptorBuilder$$anonfun$9.apply(Reflector.scala:115)
at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch$$anon$2.apply(Exception.scala:137)
at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch$$anon$2.apply(Exception.scala:135)
at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.apply(Exception.scala:106)
at org.json4s.reflect.Reflector$ClassDescriptorBuilder.constructorsAndCompanion(Reflector.scala:115)
at org.json4s.reflect.Reflector$ClassDescriptorBuilder.result(Reflector.scala:156)
at org.json4s.reflect.Reflector$.createDescriptor(Reflector.scala:50)
at org.json4s.reflect.Reflector$$anonfun$describe$1.apply(Reflector.scala:44)
at org.json4s.reflect.Reflector$$anonfun$describe$1.apply(Reflector.scala:44)
at org.json4s.reflect.package$Memo.apply(package.scala:39)
at org.json4s.reflect.Reflector$.describe(Reflector.scala:44)
at org.json4s.Extraction$.extract(Extraction.scala:330)
```

```

It seems like a bug in the underlying jar file which is resolved. But I am just wondering if this is the right approach, can I simply bump the jar version for json4s?
The *pact-jvm-provider-spring-mvc* is not touched in a while, and the 0.5.0 version never released. Again note that I don't need spring-mvc. I just want to test Pact against my rest api. 
I thought there might be another way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the request body matches what the api expects.

I've gotten similar errors (but from jackson) when that was the case.